# auto-unwiden ediff frame on quit

Tags: hooks, ediff

So in ediff I can press `m` to widen the frame but if I quit before pressing it again to restore to the original size, then the frame stays that size. I'd like to automate this so that if I forgot to press `m` before quitting ediff, it will "press" `m` for me.

I found some elisp that claims to do this:

```
(add-hook 'ediff-cleanup-hook
  (lambda () (if ediff-wide-display-p 'ediff-toggle-wide-display)))
```

However, it doesn't seem to be having any effect. Can this be done after all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kovrik on IRC provided me with something that works:

```
(defun my-toggle-ediff-wide-display ()
  "Turn off wide-display mode (if was enabled) before quitting ediff."
  (when ediff-wide-display-p
    (ediff-toggle-wide-display)))

(add-hook 'ediff-cleanup-hook 'my-toggle-ediff-wide-display)
```

I'm new to elisp, can someone tell me why this works and not what I had? I imagine it has to do with `ediff-wide-display-p` having a different value when I use it in a lambda, or something to do with a buffer local variable or whatever.

Comment: A function is generally wrapped in parentheses, unless it is passed as an argument to another function in the form of a symbol . . .

Comment: Can you elaborate? How does that relate to this? What I had was a lambda, which I was told evaluates to itself.

Comment: The problem was `'ediff-toggle-wide-display` instead of `(ediff-toggle-wide-display)`.  In the `add-hook` example in the *answer* above, `'my-toggle-ediff-wide-display` is being passed as an argument to `add-hook` in the form of a symbol.

Comment: Ohhh you're right, I can't believe that slipped past me. Thanks!